# How to validate a valid month / year between a range

Tags: php, regex, validation

How can I validate the date input from users following the format `mm/yyyy` and also the `yyyy` range is from `2002` until `2030`. So the month should be between `1` to `12` and all of the years below `2002` and `2030` in invalid. Here is my current regular expression:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20)\d\d$
```

Comment: The answer is you shouldn't. Just capture the numbers and check them.

Comment: It's a system and I'm only allow to change the regex to validate the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're forced to use regex, here you are:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20(?:0[2-9]|[12]\d|30))$
```

It works similar to the month validation pattern you wrote - `0[2-9]` matches 2002 to 2009, `[12]\d` matches 2010 to 2029, and `30` matches 2030.

Answer (score 0):

You can Validate a Gregorian date using the checkdate() function; however this requires you to be in a DateTime/Date format, it's useful for making sure people don't do stuff like: 35/02/2014

However, something like this could work?

```
([0-2][0-9]|31)\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(200[2-9]|20[1-2][0-9]|2030)
```

And then cast the string to a DateTime object and run the checkdate() function upon it to check it's gregorian?

Comment: Your regex allow year `2039`, isn't it?

Comment: From what I see, it allows year 2000.

Comment: It now allow month = `19`.

Comment: Not yet, it matches `00/10/2010` or `31/02/2015` but not `30/12/2014` and moreover OP doesn't want to chek the day.

Comment: (0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(200[2-9]|20[1-2][0-9]|2030)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0[1-9]|(1[0-2]+)+)\/(20(0[2-9]|([1-2][0-9])|30))$
```

You can use this pattern. You can test it here also. http://regexr.com/3a60s

Breakdown:

`^(`

1. `0[1-9]|(1[0-2]+)+)`
2. `\/`
3. `(20(0[2-9]|([1-2][0-9])|30)`

`)$`

Explanation:

1. Matches between 01 to 09, or 10 to 12.
2. Matches your "`/`"
3. Matches 3 year sets starting with 20.

   - 2002 to 2009 with `0[2-9]`
   - or 2010 to 2029 with `[1-2][0-9]`
   - or 2030, which is matched with the literal `30`

Comment: Your pattern matches `11111/2002`. You have to remove the `+` after `1[0-2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You may check by pattern.. this way

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20(?:0[2-9]|[12]\d|30))$" />
```